# Weight Painting - mesh going purple

Tags: weight-painting

Just started experimenting with Weight Painting, and for some reason, if I've painted anything on a mesh and then right click on an armature, the mesh goes purple. What's happening here? How do you fix this? Also, is there any way of being able to select between meshes with right click if you have Select set to Left Click instead?

Thanks